# How to Convert Unicode Text File With URLs to ANSI using URL Encoding

Tags: c#, unicode, urlencode

I have some large text files containing URLs. They are encoded in a UCS-2 Little Endian. They contain all kinds of links that contain: Arabian, Chinese, Japanese, Korean, Russian and all languages you can think of in their URL.

My goal is to create a script that will URL encode automatically all of these links and save them in an ANSI encoded file.

Example:

These are some of the original links:

```
http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/あきれて物が言えない
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Дактиль
http://zh.wikipedia.org/zh/垃圾食品
http://abunawaf.com/سيارات-الملوك-وورثتهم-صور
http://ko.wiktionary.org/wiki/가능해지다
```

These need to become:

```
http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%e3%81%82%e3%81%8d%e3%82%8c%e3%81%a6%e7%89%a9%e3%81%8c%e8%a8%80%e3%81%88%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%d0%94%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c
http://zh.wikipedia.org/zh/%e5%9e%83%e5%9c%be%e9%a3%9f%e5%93%81
http://abunawaf.com/%d8%b3%d9%8a%d8%a7%d8%b1%d8%a7%d8%aa-%d8%a7%d9%84%d9%85%d9%84%d9%88%d9%83-%d9%88%d9%88%d8%b1%d8%ab%d8%aa%d9%87%d9%85-%d8%b5%d9%88%d8%b1
http://ko.wiktionary.org/wiki/%ea%b0%80%eb%8a%a5%ed%95%b4%ec%a7%80%eb%8b%a4
```

I've used C# to do that. I've tried using the HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode method like this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string path = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        string enpath = @"c:\temp\entest.txt";

        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);

        for (int i = 0; i < 72; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode(lines[i]) + Environment.NewLine);
            System.IO.File.AppendAllText(enpath, HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode(lines[i]) + Environment.NewLine, Encoding.ASCII);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();

    }
```

It seems to be converting them very well except for one small bug: if the URL contains a question mark, it doesn't convert anything after it. This is a big handicap for me as I have a lot of links that contain question marks.

Example:

```
http://www.alkousy.com/showthread.php?4113-ÇáÚáã-ÈÇááøóå-åæ-ßäÒ-ÇáÃäÈíÇÁ-ææÑËÊåã-ãä-ÇáãÄãäíä
```

is being converted as:

```
http://www.alkousy.com/showthread.php?4113-?????-???????-??-???-????????-???????-??-????????
```

This is totally unacceptable for me, and I'm looking for another solution. I've tried Uri.EscapeDataString as well, but this guy converts everything including the // and :

Is there a quick solution for this without custom coding anything?

Comment: There is no such encoding as “ANSI”.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `Uri` class instead:

```
var url = "http://www.alkousy.com/あきれて物が言.php?4113-ÇáÚáã-ÈÇááøóå-åæ-ßäÒ-ÇáÃäÈíÇ";
var uri = new Uri(url, UriKind.Absolute);
Console.WriteLine(uri.GetComponents(UriComponents.AbsoluteUri, UriFormat.UriEscaped));
```

Which will output:

```
http://www.alkousy.com/%E3%81%82%E3%81%8D%E3%82%8C%E3%81%A6%E7%89%A9%E3%81%8C%E8
%A8%80.php?4113-%C3%87%C3%A1%C3%9A%C3%A1%C3%A3-%C3%88%C3%87%C3%A1%C3%A1%C3%B8%C3
%B3%C3%A5-%C3%A5%C3%A6-%C3%9F%C3%A4%C3%92-%C3%87%C3%A1%C3%83%C3%A4%C3%88%C3%AD%C
3%87
```

The Uri class understands that the URI is an actual URI, so it knows not to encode the protocol. So we can adjust your code to this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    string path = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
    string enpath = @"c:\temp\entest.txt";

    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);

    for (int i = 0; i < 72; i++)
    {
        var uri = new Uri(lines[i], UriKind.Absolute);
        var escaped = uri.GetComponents(UriComponents.AbsoluteUri, UriFormat.UriEscaped);
        Console.WriteLine(escaped);
        System.IO.File.AppendAllText(enpath, escaped + Environment.NewLine, Encoding.ASCII);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Based on the comments, we can implement this as a `foreach` loop:

```
foreach (var line in lines)
{
    Uri uri;
    if (Uri.TryCreate(line, UriKind.Absolute, out uri))
    {
        var escaped = uri.GetComponents(UriComponents.AbsoluteUri, UriFormat.UriEscaped);
        Console.WriteLine(escaped);
        System.IO.File.AppendAllText(enpath, escaped + Environment.NewLine, Encoding.ASCII);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks! This code seems to do the job very well! It's a bit out of my scope, but I will try to investigate more the Uri class now, thanks a lot!

Comment: just one quick question out of curiosity, do you think this can also be accomplished by using Stream instead? And whether Stream is a better idea if the files are really large?

Comment: I would instead use [`File.ReadLines`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and use a `foreach` over that. That is capable of handling large files.

Comment: Great, I'm gonna go with File.ReadLines / foreach then. Infinite gratitude!